# Why does my Java application need to be restarted every time after the database package is compiled?

Tags: java, web-applications, oracle11g

I am calling a Oracle database package in my application. If I recompile that package, then my application need to be restarted, else it will say code modified.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: When you say database package do you mean PLSQL? If so this may be a question for Oracle. Otherwise could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Does your package use package wide variables? Then those variable references become invalid when recompiling the package. More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to restart your application, just recreate your connections to database, it's because the driver hold a in memory a link with the previous compiled version of your package and so a new connection will get the update version. It's usually is observed on PLSQL/Oracle databases and it's a thing related with the driver not with Java.
Have a look in this question/answer, [Does Tomcat use cached versions of pl/sql modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885499/does-tomcat-use-cached-versions-of-pl-sql-modules), its have some suggestions to how overcome this situations.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle packages can have state information.  Within the body of the package you can have variables defined at the package level.  These "globals" exist between calls to the database and are associated with a database session.  When the package is recompiled (I'm guessing this is what you're seeing in the error as  "modified") you could have added or removed variables from the package body so Oracle has to throw out the old state of the package and make a fresh one.  It warns you that it did this by raising an **ORA-04068: Existing state of packages has been discarded**.

If you're using some sort of connection pooling (including [Database Resident Connection Pooling](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc002.htm#ADMIN12347)), which is typical on a web server, you need to remember that the connection isn't really closed when you close it in your code.  It's just returned to the pool when the app server is done with it (by calling Closed, Dispose, etc) but it stays open and Oracle Database doesn't notice that you consider it "closed".  When a new connection is needed it grabs the old connection from the pool and gives it to the server.  Since Oracle never closed the connection the session is still active from the last time it was used.  If the package was changed since the last time the connection was used you could still get an ORA-04068 even though to your code it looks like you had just opened a brand new connection.  Restarting your application server would cause all connections in the pool to be closed at shutdown and recreated at start-up which would seem to be how you're solving the problem right now.

- The best option if you can do it is to use [edition based redefinition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-mar/o20asktom-098897.html).  This way you compile the new package but only new sessions will use the new code.  Old sessions will continue to use the old code.  Again if you're doing things like bug fixes this may not be ideal since you're at the mercy of the old sessions replacing the new before they'll pick up the fixes.
- A second option is if you know you don't care if the internal state of that particular package is lost is to just run the package procedure/function call again.  Oracle won't give you the ORA-04068 again (unless the package is recompiled again).

Hope this helps.  If not some more details about the exact error your seeing and your environment would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks it helped me. But i was not clear about the second Option. And this clues take me to the below link and was really helpful.https://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/avoiding-ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded/

Comment: That article is very helpful regarding this issue.  With the second option I was just saying you will only get the ORA-04068 once after recompilation.  So if you were to call the proc from Java and catch the exception if the error is an ORA-04068 you should be able to repeat the exact same call and have it work this time.  Not the cleanest solution but it would work.

Also if any of the responses your seeing on this page were helpful please up vote the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Flushing the shared pool after re-compile that package can help as it will force the connected sessions to do a re-parse whenever they try to access that package for the first time after the shared pool flush.

With DBA privilege:
***alter system flush shared_pool;***

Please note that other applications can experience some slowness for a little time after flushing the shared pool as their connected session will also be forced re-parse their SQL/PLSQL statements as well, so it's recommended to plan for package recompile along with flushing the shared pool out of peak time.